# Liferay 7 - OSGi components Web Console (Apache Felix) Integration

Tags: osgi, integration, apache-felix, liferay-7, liferay-dxp

Is there any way by which I can integrate Apache Felix Web Console with Liferay DXP? As DXP and AEM both having OSGi based container. So, I wanted to integrate AEM module into DXP by which we can manage modules by web.

Answer (score 4):

Yes that is possible,  **Apache Felix Web Console** in **Liferay DXP** server OSGi container.

Idea behind is to integration of Apache Felix Web Console OSGi component on Liferay DXP, because same OSGi component available in AEM for managing OSGi components. So, I wanted to check whether it works with DXP or not? By which developer can manage the components and services with the help of clicks in DXP as well ;)

Step By Step Installation :

1. Open GoGo shell
2. Hit command `install http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/felix/org.apache.felix.webconsole/4.3.0/org.apache.felix.webconsole-4.3.0.jar`
3. hit command `lb` --> see the process description
4. After that you will find the pid of current component what you installed like:
   `4457 |Installed | 1|Apache Felix Web Management Console (All In One) (4.2.16.all)` here **4457** is your `pid`
5. Hit command `start 4457`
6. Hit command `lb`
7. Now you can see **4457** process has been activated `4457 | Active | 1 | Apache Felix Web Management Console (All In One) (4.2.16.all)`
8. Hit URL in browser `http://<portalUrl>/o/system/console` here you can see **/o/system/console** is the URL where you can access the WEB CONSOLE of OSGi component.
9. Authenticate Popup will come on broswer, provide the default credentials of admin

   - username : admin
   - password : admin
10. After that you will see all the components which are available on your container. Check the below screenshot.
    [image]